# Postgres truncate timestamp gives slightly unexpected output

Tags: postgresql, truncate

I have a table called device_data which looks something like below

```
      Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id               | integer                     |           |          | 
 date             | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 upload           | real                        |           |          | 
 download         | real                        |           |          |
```

Now when I do a daily truncation on data, I do something like below

**First query**

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('day', date) as daily,
  avg(upload) as avg_upload,
  avg(download) as avg_download
FROM device_info
WHERE
  date BETWEEN '2022-10-07 10:28:46' AND '2022-11-06 10:28:46'
GROUP BY daily
ORDER BY daily;
```

I get the below result

```
       daily        |     avg_upload     |    avg_download    
---------------------+--------------------+--------------------
 2022-10-07 00:00:00 | 41.691493286006484 | 41.571846902122246
 2022-10-08 00:00:00 | 23.348292880412536 | 25.450085919814388
 2022-10-09 00:00:00 | 14.496747577637498 |  15.03089042501744
 2022-10-10 00:00:00 | 108.54434560738528 |   296.091238792341
 2022-10-11 00:00:00 |  163.0374394524876 |  140.3484673696004
 2022-10-12 00:00:00 | 240.54915519812943 |   74.1109145983748
 2022-10-13 00:00:00 |  94.02086876518116 | 162.71920269686137
 2022-10-14 00:00:00 | 58.254662611037375 | 62.832775704871615
 2022-10-15 00:00:00 | 33.759871942986635 |  27.21136256905281
 ...
```

Now if I run the below query which I assume does the same thing, I get slightly different result

**Second query**

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('month', date) + date_part('day', date)::int / 1 * interval '1 day' AS daily,
  avg(upload) as avg_upload,
  avg(download) as avg_download
FROM device_info
WHERE
  date BETWEEN '2022-10-07 10:28:46' and '2022-11-06 10:28:46'
GROUP BY daily
ORDER BY daily ASC;
```

I get the below result

```
       daily         |     avg_upload     |    avg_download    
---------------------+--------------------+--------------------
 2022-10-08 00:00:00 | 41.691493286006484 | 41.571846902122246
 2022-10-09 00:00:00 | 23.348292880412536 | 25.450085919814388
 2022-10-10 00:00:00 | 14.496747577637498 |  15.03089042501744
 2022-10-11 00:00:00 | 108.54434560738528 |   296.091238792341
 2022-10-12 00:00:00 |  163.0374394524876 |  140.3484673696004
 2022-10-13 00:00:00 | 240.54915519812943 |   74.1109145983748
 2022-10-14 00:00:00 |  94.02086876518116 | 162.71920269686137
 2022-10-15 00:00:00 | 58.254662611037375 | 62.832775704871615
 2022-10-16 00:00:00 | 33.759871942986635 |  27.21136256905281
```

So you can see although both the output appears to be similar, the second query shifts the data by one day ie

**First query (first row)**

```
2022-10-07 00:00:00 | 41.691493286006484 | 41.571846902122246
```

**Second query (first row)**

```
2022-10-08 00:00:00 | 41.691493286006484 | 41.571846902122246
```

So where exactly is my second query going wrong (my assumption being that both queries do the same thing)?

**Note:** The reason I am asking this is because I would want a `weekly` truncation of data and a `6 days` truncation of data where the second query can come handy.

Comment: I don't see this `SELECT date_trunc('daily', date) ...` working as there is no  `daily` precision here [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). Sure you don't mean `SELECT date_trunc('day', date) ...?

Comment: As to second query you are doing `2022-10-01 00:00:00 + interval '7 days' = 2022-10-08 00:00:00 ` which is the same a doing `1 + 7 = 8` .

Comment: @AdrianKlaver you are right. It was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So where exactly is my second query going wrong?

You are assuming that `date_trunc()` returns a timestamp with the day of month set to zero, which it of course does not, it returns the first day of the month. So you have to reduce your offset by one day:

```
...
  date_trunc('month', date) + (date_part('day', date)::int - 1) / 1 * interval '1 day' AS daily,
...
```

Remember:
There are only two hard problems in computer sience:

- cache invalidation
- naming things
- off-by-one errors

Comment: @SebDieBin Now I understand where it was going wrong. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @SebDieBin just another question, if I do it on an `hour` or `minute` basis like `date_trunc('hour', date)`, do I need to make any adjustment to the second query?

Comment: @SouvikRay Since `hour` and `minute` start counting from zero (unlike `day`) you would not need an additional offset. It is only `day` (and `month`) that do not truncate to zero.